# MS Access datasheet won't update based on combo box

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a split form based on a query. In the header I have a combo box that works as a filter for the query. So when I change the value of the combo box I expect the datasheet to update (On Change Event Requery). Now the problem is that the datasheet doesn't reflect the new filter.

When I execute the query itself (which is linked to the combo box) everything works fine. Also, when I update an underlying table of the query (e.g., add a new entry) and then change the value of the combo box, the new entry will show up in the datasheet, but not the filter. So based on that I conclude that the query is right and also the event works.

Any idea what's going on? I'm getting insane over this...

Answer (score 0):

It's a workaround, but if you are positive the code works, you can create an "Apply Filter" button that, on the execute event, runs the code. Not super elegant, but effective.